# What's the best way for gaming to access other classes' members?

Tags: c++, class, oop, game-development

I am new here and my Q was too long and I took isim's advice and shortened the Q. I'm just learning to ask questions. Thanks to isim.

I am new on C++ and OOP too, working on a game, using some great libraries (Bullet for physics, Ogre for rendering, RakNet for networking etc.) Although my game is working, I have a feeling that doing something wrong.

I have this issue for every lib that I use. To be short and sweet, I'll exemplify just using Bullet and assume that we have only two classes (Game and Object)

```
class Game
{
public:
    btDiscreteDynamicsWorld *bulletWorld;

    Game();
    ~Game();
    void UpdateWorld();
};

class Object
{
public:
    btRigidBody *body;
    Object() { bulletWorld->addRigidBody(body); };
};
```

and here is the main:

```
int main()
{
    Game myGame;
    while(1)
        myGame.UpdateWorld(); // this is THE GAME LOOP
    return 0;
}
```

Too simple isn't it? Here my problem is, if I create an object and put it to the world, I must call this:
`bulletWorld->addRigidBody(body)`
So at the moment, I can't create an object with:
`Object *myObj = new Object(); //the Object class cannot access the Game class' members`
I know I can pass the *bulletWorld pointer as an argument like this:
`Object(btDiscreteDynamicsWorld *bulletWorld);`
and that way my game is working like a charm. Nevertheless, I don't feel so comfortable with the fact that I have more libs than just Bullet, and for every single method of my classes which need, I have to pass pointers as arguments over and over. So, if I have 20,000 chars in my source code now, 10,000 of them are pointer arguments and this disturbs me.

Is this normal and the best way or is there any better way to do what I want. I was thinking about to create objects using a createObject() method in Game class, instead of creating with Object class and it seems will solve my problem but then, no need other classes and do everything in Game class, it looks like not C++ and OOP style, look like just C style. So what can I do?

Comment: For a better chance of getting a response from the community, please find a way to condense your question, and get to the point, and show only the relevant codes: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should avoid using `gets`.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's just for test purpose. Later, my game will have a GUI menu and not use DOS fortunately :)

Comment: Is there any good reason you're using a pointer with dynamic memory and creating an extra liability to yourself for `myGame`?

Comment: You hit a good point. I think I shouldn't use dynamic memory unless I have to and missed that one. Changed it and still works. I guess she comes from tutorials that I read :) Besides, I wonder that why all tutorials especially about gaming use dynamic memory even that's not necessary? Can you simply explain it here or should I ask a new Q for that?

Comment: @allyozturk I think it mostly stems from the fact that games like Quake(1|2|3) or Doom3 more recently are often a go-to resource for people wanting a good example of game engine source code, and any C++ in those games is just C w/ classes; not exactly the best to learn from if you want a modern C++ code-base!

Comment: @CoffeeandCode yeah you're right. Yesterday I took a peek into source codes of Quake3 and Half-Life 1. Quake3 has been coded in C, hence I went to HL1. Then realized some other thing, this is from world.cpp `===== world.cpp ========================================================
precaches and defs for entities and other data that must always be available.` `extern CGraph WorldGraph;
extern CSoundEnt *pSoundEnt;
extern CBaseEntity *g_pLastSpawn;` So I think that if Valve is using extern why I cannot? For now I go RPGillespie's way but maybe I will use externs if I need to.

Comment: @allyozturk just because somebody else did it doesn't mean it's a good idea! Global variables do have their place, but I really don't think that is within a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to think more about who is responsible for what. World objects should be responsible for handling world things, local objects should be responsible for handling local things. If I were designing this game, main would probably look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    Game *myGame = new Game();
    Object * enemy1 = new Object();
    Object * hero1 = new Object();
    myGame->addObject(enemy1); //This takes care of adding the object to the physics engine, since Game objects in your case are responsible for the world
    myGame->addObject(hero1); //Same as above; Game will take care of setting up hero1 in the world context
    while(1)
        myGame->UpdateWorld(); // this is THE GAME LOOP
    delete myGame;        
    return 0;
}
```

Your Game `addObject` method will look something like:

```
void addObject(Object * obj)
{
    bulletWorld->addRigidBody(obj->getBody());
    ...
}
```

Comment: It makes sense. I think this is what I want and will try in this way, if I can make it work, then will accept this, if I can't, then ask for help from you again :) Thanks.

Comment: Hey again, I have tried but it didn't work for me. Then I realized that I've should changed my question and condensed it. Please take a look at it again.

Comment: Also, you probably don't need to be using `new` to allocate dynamic memory if the game loop is also in main. Just initialize it normally with `Game myGame;` and `myGame.updateWorld()`

Comment: That's absolutely what I looking for, thank you too much buddy, you saved my days :) and the memory thing, already done, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need singletons, it is your game and you are not going to declare classes you need only once multiple times.

Just make your classes required everywhere global and (i) either make all required methods `public` (ii) or declare the classes allowed to access as `friend`.

Otherwise, using pointer is also perfectly valid, and which way is better as often depends... yet, you should better use smart pointers (more detailed, `shared_ptr` with in the classes and one `unique_ptr` somewhere) to better indicate the ownership relations.

Comment: Making a class global is a good idea? As I mentioned, in the first case I thought of making global variables but read a lot about it's not recommended. So, decided to not use global, and "static" also. Speaking of `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`, they could be perfect but I also read about them and couldn't get anything. I guess I need more progression on OOP.

Comment: Whether it is a good idea as always depends on your needs, but yes, it is one possible alternative here, although I would probably also rather go with the pointer stuff... it's simply less "hard-coded", and thus allows to use other instantiations for testing, etc. The smart pointer stuff adds some memory-leak safety here, as well as the principal information who owns the pointer. It's like a car you share with your neighbours: you can use it, but only the guy who owns the car is allowed to throw it away.